# Issue with deploying EAR file contains jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar in WebSpher 8

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, application-server

We have an issue with deploying our EAR file on *Websphere 8.5.0.1* stack. Ear contains  `jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar` which has package defined [`1.0/org/apache/xml/resolver/tools`], but application treats it as [`1/0/org/apache/xml/resolver/tools`] instead.

Issue is trivial, were we get some warning messages, but doesn't look good

> WARNING: Failed to open resource [
>   1/0/org/apache/xml/resolver/tools/CatalogResolver.class ] from module
>   [ WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar ]

I understand this is because annotation processing enabled in WAS8.501 and not appeared in previous version of Websphere server. After some research we found we can set it to ignore scanning, some thing like shown below.

> Ignore-Scanning-Archives :  jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar
>   Ignore-Scanning-Packages :1.0

But did not work for me.

Any alternative idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between 2.1.13 and 2.1.2 - all the classes with 1 are not thre in .13. Compare http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-jaxb-xjc/2.1.13 with /2.1.12. You either take the 2.1.13 Stable or you some MAVEN explanation is required

Comment: I am Server doesn't matter - its on WAS8 with Java 7

Comment: 2.1.13 also has 1.0 package!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update]

> We have checked with IBM about this issue, and they have confirmed its
>   an issue with Websphere 8.5.0.1. They will be fixing in Websphere
>   8.5.0.3